# How many categories of rates of increase are there?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

The Fibonacci Series increases pretty fast, but not as much as $2^x$. Of course $x!$ is even faster increasing and Knuth's Arrow notation produces unfathomable numbers.

I was wondering if there is a particular arrangement and categorization for these rates of increase.

These are the ones I could come up with:

1. $\log(x)$
2. $x$
3. Arithmetic Series
4. Recursive Artihmetic Series (Fibonacci)
5. Geometric Series i.e. $c^x$
6. $x!$
7. Exponent towers $c^{x^x}$
8. $x\uparrow$

Those are the only ones I could imagine, but I'm sure there are more that I don't know about. I've tried looking around but search engines are not understanding what I'm looking for with the keywords I'm using.

Also, how many of them are seen in real life? I think the Knuth's notation has been strictly used for probability and theoretical things.

Comment: There's no essential difference between 4 and 5 as $F_n\sim \phi^n$. Similar for 2 vs. 3. Also, you are missing out $x^n$. And if you are going so fine-grained, what about $\ln\ln\ln\ln n$?

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot Fibonacci could be approximated like that. That's a good example for my question, $ \ln \ln \ln \ln n$. How can one categorize rates of increase? How *should* one categorize rates of increase?